# "Reading up" on а subject

Tags: перевод, выражения, глаголы

I would like to know the conventional and/or colloquial way in Russian to express that one is reading up on a subject.  In English, to read up on/about something means to inform oneself about a subject through much reading and research; typically this refers to establishing or refreshing one's basic understanding of a subject. It also applies to multiple contexts (professional, academic, casual).

> I'm reading up on popular chess openings (here, familiarizing oneself with)

```
я ознакамливаюсь с шахматными дебютами
```

> I'm reading up about trunk paralysis, a disease specific to elephants.

```
Я осведомляюсь о параличе хобота — болезнь поражающая исключительно слонов.
```

Do these sound normal to a native speaker? Here are some other rough translations I could come up with, from most formal to least formal in register:

```
я информирую себя о...
я пытаюсь разузнать о...
я захожу в тему чего-л.
?я начитиваюсь статей о?
```

Are there any other common expressions I am missing?  How would a native speaker express that they are "reading up" on something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Осведомля́ться, ознака́мливаться, информи́ровать** are all very formal. It is impossible to "информи́ровать себя́" (I hereby inform myself... )

"Я чита́ю" is quite universal:

- Я чита́ю о параличе́ хо́бота у слоно́в.

Or if you want to sound more casual:

- Я тут ко́е-что почи́тываю о слона́х.

In the past:

- Я тут подначита́лся немно́го о слона́х. Ока́зывается, у них быва́ет парали́ч хо́бота.

You could also say something semi-ironic like "восполня́ю пробе́лы своего́ образова́ния в нау́ке о слона́х."

Comment: I might be opinionated on this, but to me `Я читаю про <тему>` sounds better than `Я читаю о <теме>`. If you want to be more specific that it is scientific research or of a greater interest, `Я читаю статьи по теме/про/о ...` is more concise.

Answer (score -1):

Я изучаю шахматные дебюты (проблему паралича хобота у слонов).

Comment: Specially to downvoters: "Charles spent his first day at the office reading up all facts and figures" - "...изучая все факты и цифры", "If you are planning to take up bee-keeping, read up about it first" - "...сперва изучите [предмет]". In both cases it comes to people's not having the slightest apprehension of the issue. So it can't come up to simply "дополнительно почитать или ознакомиться".